# Realising a nested subquery (from a second select)

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

In the Access Backend I have nested one select into another.

To do this I created first the inner select 'abfCombineContactWithSupporter' based on two tables and stored it as separate select. Then I called this select in another (outer) select. This way I combined the first select 'abfCombineContactWithSupporter' with a third table.

The code of the *outer select*:

```
INSERT INTO tblSupporters
SELECT tblMailingContacts.*
FROM tblMailingContacts 
LEFT JOIN abfCombineContactWithSupporter 
ON tblMailingContacts.[ID-Contact] = abfCombineContactWithSupporter.[ID-Contact]
WHERE (((abfCombineContactWithSupporter.Supporter)='ocl'));
```

The code of the *nested select 'abfCombineContactWithSupporter'*:

```
SELECT tblCompany.Supporter, tblContacts.[ID-Contact]
FROM tblContacts 
LEFT JOIN tblCompany 
ON tblContacts.[ID-Company] = tblCompany.[ID-Company];
```

In the Access Backend it works fine.

But now I need to realise this in pure vba (without graphical backend) and have to put both strings together into one query-string. (In this special case it is not possible to store the inner select as object in the backend.)

For me it seems to be a subquery but did not figure out how to do combine the two scripts ... any help is welcome.

*Sorry for my English. It is not my native language.*

Comment: What did you try and what was error/undesired results? Did you simply replace the query name with its `SELECT` statement wrapped in parentheses and keeping query name as alias?

Comment: Also, I am curious about this requirement: *But now I need to realise this in pure vba*. Do note: stored queries tend to be more efficient than VBA queries as the Access engines compiles and saves the best execution plan and statistics with saved queries where as VBA strings are run on the fly.

Comment: I had indeed a lot of attempts this afternoon (with the select-statement in parenthese too of course) ... but not with giving it an alias like in the answer of Erik von Asmuth. Unfortunately I don't have to much experience in sql

Comment: The requirement to realise it *in pure vba* is based on the condition that the query-string will be manipulated in a loop by using some vars ... the task of the project is to move datas between several databases. Code is just a sample.

Comment: Do you mean changing column names or passing different values like *ocl*? Because there is a concept of parameterization that still can use stored queries.

Comment: Yes. Changing values but names of tables (and the databases behind them) too. A very special project where a database is split into (dynamic) 3, 5 or 8 parts and brought back together monthly. This will be administrated by an additional external 'access database' which manage the data transfer using connected tables. Indeed I tried to solve the task with 'parameter vars' in the selections ... but the numbers of the needed selections was to high and the possible automatisation was not flexible enough even because of the dynamic table names. Manipulating the query string is much more flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can usually just swap the query name with the subquery:

```
INSERT INTO tblSupporters
SELECT tblMailingContacts.*
FROM tblMailingContacts
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT tblCompany.Supporter,
          tblContacts.[ID-Contact]
   FROM tblContacts
   LEFT JOIN tblCompany ON tblContacts.[ID-Company] = tblCompany.[ID-Company]) AS subCombineContactWithSupporter
   ON tblMailingContacts.[ID-Contact] = subCombineContactWithSupporter.[ID-Contact]
WHERE (((subCombineContactWithSupporter.Supporter)='ocl'));
```

Of course, in really specific situations this can cause errors, but I see no reason it should here.

Comment: Great. That works perfect! Exactly what I was searching for the last afternoon. The key indeed is to ad an alias to the subquery `AS subCombineContactWithSupporter`. To do this was new to me ... Thx a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just join them:

```
INSERT INTO tblSupporters
SELECT tblMailingContacts.*
FROM tblMailingContacts 
LEFT JOIN tblContacts 
ON tblMailingContacts.[ID-Contact] = tblContacts.[ID-Contact]
LEFT JOIN tblCompany 
ON tblContacts.[ID-Company] = tblCompany.[ID-Company]
WHERE (((tblCompany.Supporter)='ocl'));
```